# Design linked list edge cases

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I'm trying to solve [design linked list](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-linked-list/) problem on leetcode.
And I have next code:

```
class MyLinkedList(
) {

data class ListNode(
    var `val`: Int
) {
    var next: ListNode? = null
}

var head: ListNode? = null
var size = 0

fun get(index: Int): Int {
    if (head == null || index >= size) return -1

    var iter = head
    for (i in 0 until index) {
        iter = iter?.next
    }

    return iter?.`val` ?: -1
}

fun addAtHead(`val`: Int) {
    val new = ListNode(`val`)
    new!!.next = head
    head = new
    size++
}

fun addAtTail(`val`: Int) {
   var iter = head
   for (i in 0 until size - 1) {
        iter = iter?.next
    }
    
    val new = ListNode(`val`)
    iter?.next = new
    size++
}

fun addAtIndex(index: Int, `val`: Int) {
    if (index > size)
        return

    if (index == 0) {
        addAtHead(`val`)
        return
    }
    
    var iter = head
    for (i in 0 until index - 1) {
        iter = iter?.next
    }
    val new = ListNode(`val`)
    iter?.next = new
    size++
}

fun deleteAtIndex(index: Int) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size - 1) return
    if (index == 0) {
        head = if (head?.next == null) null else head?.next
        size--
        return
    }
    
    var iter = head
    for (i in 0 until index - 1) {
        iter = iter?.next
    }
  
    iter?.next = iter?.next?.next
    size--
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, my solution is not working unde the next test case:

```
["MyLinkedList","addAtHead","addAtTail","addAtIndex","get","deleteAtIndex","get"]
[[],[1],[3],[1,2],[1],[1],[1]]
```

Instead of `[null,null,null,null,2,null,3]` I'm getting `[null,null,null,null,2,null,-1]`.
And it seems that deletion is not working, but I don't understand why.
Could you help me to find the bug in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

- `addAtTail` does not update `head` when the list was empty. You could do like you have done elsewhere, and call `addAtHead` when the list is empty:

  ```
  if (head == null) return addAtHead(`val`)
  ```
- `addAtIndex` does not make the remainder of the list follow after the inserted node, but instead truncates the list at the inserted node. Set the `next` reference of the inserted node:

  ```
  val new = ListNode(`val`)
  new.next = iter?.next  // don't lose the remainder of the list
  iter?.next = new
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about language syntax but here I found the bug in logic of function "addAtIndex(...)". You are doing the following.

```
val new = ListNode(`val`)
iter?.next = new
```

You forgot to add the rest of the linked list i.e. "iter->next" to the end of new, hence your linked list ended at that index and rest of the list reference is simply lost.